# rollout not happening automatically on a live copy

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, content-management-system, aem, rollout

In the SiteAdmin console,I tried to create a live copy with EN locale as the blueprint,by selecting the option new-->new Live copy.(however in documentation it is specified that we need to select new-->new site).If I select new-->new site only the parent page is seen visible in the live copy.Hence gone with new-->new Live copy, then have I choosen the rollout config "Activate on BluePrint Activaton" for my Live Copy.Then I have added one text component in the blueprint page and activated the page.However, in the live copy created for this blueprint that particular change is not reflected.May I know how we can automatically rollout the changes from blueprint to its live copies.

Thanks,
Balaji

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the **Activate on Blueprint Activation** rollout configuration is not meant to ensure changes in your blueprint page will be reflected onto the live copy page. All it does is activate the live copy as soon as your corresponding blueprint is activated.

To achieve your requirement, I believe the **push on modify** configuration would be more appropriate.

If you open up **push on modify** on the roll-out config, you will find the following sync actions

```
ContentCopyAction 
ContentUpdateAction
```

are enabled. These  actions allow you to make sure that your blueprint page is copied. Hence selecting the **push on modify** configuration would satisfy your requirement.

Alternatively you may wish to modify the **Activate on Blueprint Activation** rollout configuration by adding the above sync actions to suit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Have you written the rollout configuration for this in etc/MSM/rolloutConfig/cqEditConfig?

There you can add the configurations. Like you can change the sling:resourceType, template from there.